# Simple cross domain ajax solution that is eBay compatible

Tags: javascript, ajax, flash, cross-domain, ebay-design-templates

I want to request a list of sizes from a database on my server (which is obviously not on ebay.co.uk's domain). I could do it entirely through flash... but it seems clumsy for a simple form. I think the ideal solution would be a javascript + flash solution. The problem is all of the sites I have found seem to have very complete solutions and ebay does not like huge chunks of javascript (I am not sure exactly which functions it allows and doesn't... but the less javascript the better).

So what I am looking for is a very small and simple cross domain ajax solution that will allow me to make requests from my server. Anyone any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) for many ways of circumventing the same-origin policy.

In your case, I would suggest http://anyorigin.com - it's simple to use and (unless you're sending volatile information) perfectly viable. It could all be done in a couple of lines of js!

Comment: I am not sure how I would implement this... it used Jquery and Jquery is a big library which ebay again does not like. Can I make a similar request in plain javascript?

Comment: jQuery aside, I don't think a jsonp approach will work on ebay anyway, they don't allow you to include off-site scripts.

Comment: JSONP works a treat. Just make the script create a script element for the remote site :p

Answer (score 0):

eBay will not allow including javascript or even iframes in item description.
The only solution for that will probably be using Flash object(that is allowed by eBay) that will communicate with server side scripting page(php/asp) which will make the request to your database.
The cross-domain communication will be between the flash and the server side page, this issue can be easily solved.